# Getting error on dynamic XML sitemap script

Tags: xml

I have a problem with my dynamic XML script. I keep getting **XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity** error and tried almost everything found around here but nothing worked. Any ideas?

The code:

```
<?php include("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT `website_url` FROM `websites`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$base_url = "http://localhost/test/www.shopperapproved.com/";
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">' . PHP_EOL;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<url>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<loc>'.$base_url. $row["website_url"] .'/</loc>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '</url>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</urlset>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. Just moved these 2 lines:

```
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . PHP_EOL;
```

at the top of the file over `include("connect.php");`

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: So I guess, the real problem is, that `include("connect.php")` adds white space or even text. You may also have a look at that file.